# Why doesn't my CSS colour transform work in IE10?

Tags: css, transform

Here is my code:

```
/* Tile colour rotation */
/*tile 1 */
@-webkit-keyframes bwe1 {
0% {background-color: #39f;}
15% {background-color: #8bc5d1;}
30% {background-color: #f8cb4a;}
45% {background-color: #95b850;}
60% {background-color: #944893;}
75% {background-color: #c71f00;}
90% {background-color: #bdb280;}
100% {background-color: #39f;}
}
@-moz-keyframes bwe1 {
0% {background-color: #39f;}
15% {background-color: #8bc5d1;}
30% {background-color: #f8cb4a;}
45% {background-color: #95b850;}
60% {background-color: #944893;}
75% {background-color: #c71f00;}
90% {background-color: #bdb280;}
100% {background-color: #39f;}
}

/* Colour changing tiles */
.metro-layout .cycle1 {-webkit-animation: bwe1 20s infinite alternate linear;   -moz-animation: bwe1 20s infinite alternate linear; }
```

These are the two sections of code I am using to define the colour rotate animation but it's not working in IE10. it is however working in Firefox, Safari and Chrome...

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should also define

```
-ms-animation: ...
```

and

```
@-ms-keyframes bwe1 { ... }
```

Since `-webkit-` and `-moz-` are vendor specific prefixes which `IE` simply ignores.

Note that you should also define the unprefixed version (`animation`, `@keyframes`) of your code for newer browsers, like latest Firefox versions.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's worked perfectly. Do you know if this function is also supported in IE9? It now works in every modern browser except that one! Thanks!

Comment: CSS3 animations are not available on IE9. There you may use transitions only